# Startup Programs from Regedit "Entries" don't work

Tags: windows-10, boot, windows-registry, process, regedit

Instead of spending time typing a password, pin, etc.  I used netplwiz to remove the password of my windows (10) username and since then the apps that were being launched at startup like Skype, Windows Defender, Onedrive and 3 other stopped from being launched at startup.
The only way that I got to start those apps as before was to create a shortcut for each app in `shell:startup` with the `"-hidden" "-minimum"`  in the target of each shortcut but I would like to get my regedit working again.
I already tried to create a local user, `sfc /scannow`, I don't see anything related to this problem in the Event Viewer Logs.
If I put anything here:  `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` the app shows in 'Task Manager' -> 'Startup' but if I remove the icons from: `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` the app/s won't launch.
My Windows just stopped reacting to the Startup entries from Regedit.

Comment: "Remove the password from Windows Startup": What does this mean. Please clarify what changes you made to your account? Was there a reason you remove the password?

Comment: Also, each question should have its own post. Right now it appears you have added a second question in the last paragraph. If this is the same question, please edit this to clarify the relationship. If it is a different question, please post it separately.

Comment: music2myear - I've removed the password with the command "netplwiz" for windows to start faster, instead of typing a password, pin, etc.

Comment: Please edit your question to add this and any other requested information. Do not just add information in the comments. Putting all the information, including updates, as edits in the original question helps get you good answers because people will not have to read through the comments to find all pertinent information.

Comment: Thank you, is it ok now? hope that someone could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved!

Restored my regedit like this:

**First** - Went to `Settings, Recovery, Advanced Startup` and opened command prompt, it starts on X:\Windows\System32

**Second** - To restore the Registry -  Typed `cd c:\Windows\System32\` - To create a folder for temporary backup files `mkdir configBak` -  To create a temporary backup of the files in the config folder `copy config configBak` To move inside the RegBack, which contains a backup of the Registry `cd config\RegBack` To copy the files from the RegBack folder to the config folder `Copy * ..\*` Did a reboot and the startup programs that were on my regedit started working again like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run `DISM`?

You could try this:

`DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`

In last case, try to use Task Scheduler.

Comment: Thank you Tiago but my problem is not being able to have the startup entries from regedit working.

Comment: @Mr_Chmod I misunderstand what you're asking for, if I come up with something I'll rewrite a new answer

Comment: I have already did sfc /scannow and found no corrupt entries but even so I tried DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth. I can use Task Scheduler but I don't want to. I just want my Regedit Startup entries working.